# Google.Apis.Sheets.v4 : Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth"

Tags: c#, .net, google-sheets, oauth-2.0, google-sheets-api

I am working on Google Sheet Api, the below attached code is working fine in development environment. After deploying website in IIS, I am phasing the belwo error. I am working with ASP.NET MVC Environment.

System.NotSupportedException: Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=131872634482-gh84b1avui5t9f5ugfv667eiotkivu1p.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A56626%2Fauthorize%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fspreadsheets" for authorization. See inner exception for details. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
at EmailDashboard.Extensions.SpreadsheetV4Extensions.GetService() in D:\Project\EmailDashboard\SourceCodeWeb\EmailDashboard\Extensions\SpreadsheetV4Extensions.cs:line 43
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.NotSupportedException: Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=131872634482-gh84b1avui5t9f5ugfv667eiotkivu1p.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A56626%2Fauthorize%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fspreadsheets" for authorization. See inner exception for details. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__1.MoveNext()<---

```
public SheetsService GetService()
{
    try
    {
        string path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/client_Secret_Sheet.json");
        UserCredential credential = null;
        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {

            string folderPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Credentials/");

            if (folderPath != null)
            {
                string filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, "SpreadsheetCredentials");
                if (Directory.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(filePath);

                    //foreach (FileInfo file in directoryInfo.GetFiles()) {
                    //    file.Delete();
                    //}

                    //foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in directoryInfo.GetDirectories()) {
                    //    dir.Delete(true);
                    //}
                }

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    new[] { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets },
                    Environment.UserName,
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(filePath, true)).Result;
            }
        }
        // Create Drive API service.
        SheetsService service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = _applicationName,
        });

        return service;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please take a moment to read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I remember it.

Answer (score 0):

So looking at your code you are trying to make an authorized client by doing:

```
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    new[] { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets },
                    Environment.UserName,
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(filePath, true)).Result;
```

This is advised for doing installed apps in your PC. For deploying this in a server you would need to change your code.

All the process and option you have is very detailed in [this page](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-mvc). Basically Google has a package to implement the authentication in MVC.

#### Reference

- NuGet Package for [Google.Apis.Auth.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Auth.MVC/)
- Github Library for [Google C# API](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am looking the same "this page". but not able to understand how i implement that code with my application. Please help me with steps to resolve the issue.

Comment: I think that the page is very self explanatory, if you are using a MVC architecture, you will have a controller. You need to implement your own controller using Drive services, and also create a new implementation of [`FlowMetaData`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/2df445ea9fce00868cf0a1ea010cb40ef6ed64a8/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth.Mvc/OAuth2/Mvc/FlowMetadata.cs). There is no much that I can do to help with the information you have provided. Try to improve your original question explaining your setup and what you are trying to achieve.